# Can we use HashMap to store shared data in HttpSession?

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

We are using HashMap to store data in HttpSession (Jetty).
We don't synchronize on put and get.
Is it possible that one request puts data into Map and the other request doesn't see that data in Map because they are from different Threads (Jetty thread pool)?

Maybe we **must** use ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: Yes, you may be better using `ConcurrentHashMap`. Anyway, why not using `HttpSession` directly instead?

Comment: We store a complex object in HttpSession. One of it's fields is a HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the state of the whole object that you store in a session is consistent between different threads.

Just replacing `HashMap` with `ConcurrentHashMap` may not be enough for that.

The only thing that `ConcurrentHashMap` will ensure is 'happens before' behavior will be enforced on values and keys stored in the map.